# Updating a field in a table based on form being submitted to another

Tags: javascript, php, sql, laravel

Please help!! I have an orders table, a restaurant stock table and a warehouse stock table. I am currently trying to build an inventory management system using PHPmyAdmin and Laravel through the IDE PHPstorm. At present I have a form submitting orders to the orders table, however what I want is that when this order is submitted, the data in the warehouse stock and restaurant stock tables is updated also. For example, 
Item: Chicken Breast
Quantity needed: 6
user presses submit, and order is uploaded to the orders table. They are able to view these orders in a previous orders view. Can someone help with an algorithm to link the three tables together, so that the quantity field is updated each time? (Restaurant stock table eg item Chicken Breast quantity will go up by 6, whilst warehouse goes down by 6)

Comment: A form does not submit to a table, it submits to a script(in an MVC framework, that script is a controller method) which inserts the data. You'll need to modify the controller method to update both tables instead of just one. Without seeing your code that's about as specific as I can get. It's probably worthwhile to add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well as an explanation of what you've tried so far to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know laravel, but at the point you process your input of quantity=6 you make your

insert into orders (quantity) values(6);

you do

update stocktable set quantity=quantity-6 where...